# Has "as-is" plural form?

Tags: grammatical-number

I wanted to shorten a sentence: "Let the procedures leave in their original state."
I wrote "Let the procedures leave  **as-is**."
Is it correct or I had to use "Let the procedures leave  **as-are**."
Has the expression **as-is** plural?

Thanks
   Frank

Comment: "as is" is an idiom and does not need number agreement with an external object.

Comment: Btw, not "leave" but maybe, "be left" or "stay."

Comment: The original sentence seems wrong to me. Procedures can't leave. You either have to say _Leave the procedures..._ or _Let the procedures be left..._.